# How to login with email in Parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am working on an app in Parse and I was wondering how to log in with just email and password. When I try to login with just email and password I get an error saying that I need to input a username as well.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

var user = PFUser()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

var signUpActive = true

@IBOutlet var username: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var email: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var password: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var signUpButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var registeredText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var loginButton: UIButton!

var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) ->    Void in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }))

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {

    if username.text == "" || password.text == "" {

        displayAlert("Error in form", message: "Please enter a username and password")


    } else {

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        activityIndicator.center = view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        var errorMessage = "Please try again later"

        if signUpActive == true {

            var userName = username.text as NSString!

            if userName.containsString("@") {
                displayAlert("Sign Up Failed", message: "Can't contain this symbol in username")
                user.username = ""
            } else {
                user.username = username.text
            }

        user.email = email.text
        user.password = password.text

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            if error == nil {

                // Signup successful


            } else {
                if let errorString = error!.userInfo?["error"] as? String {

                    errorMessage = errorString

                }

                self.displayAlert("Failed Signup", message: errorMessage)

            }

        })

        } else {

            PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text, password: password.text, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                if user != nil {
                    // Logged in!
                } else {

                    if let errorString = error!.userInfo?["error"] as? String {

                        errorMessage = errorString

                    }

                    self.displayAlert("Failed Login", message: errorMessage)

                }

            })

        }

    }

}

@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {

    if signUpActive == true {

        signUpButton.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        registeredText.text = "Not registered?"

        loginButton.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        signUpActive = false

    } else {

        signUpButton.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        registeredText.text = "Already registered?"

        loginButton.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        signUpActive = true
    }

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    username.delegate = self
    password.delegate = self

}

@IBAction func forgotPassword(sender: AnyObject) {

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: The username would be the email address, there is no way around this/ Have users register with their email address and validate it. Cheers,

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: @theActuary Sure. I tried to set the username to be the email if there is an @ in it but it didn't work because it looks like Parse only passes through username and password, as logins.

Comment: @Switz 's good advice is to set the username to be the email address, so you wouldn't do any check on the username (as your code does, looking for an @).  Just ask the user for an email address, don't ask for a username, validate the email address syntax, then set `user.username = email.text` and `user.email = email.text` and `user.password = password.text`

Comment: @danh Thanks but would you know how to create both a username and password?

Comment: Doesn't my comment indicate that?  See how it sets username, password and email?

Comment: @danh Oh ok thanks! Sorry.

Comment: Don't use the email as the username. See my answer for more details :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a username for the app. It is a required field. However if you do not want to use a username simply use the current user's object ID so you don't have to worry to much about it and people will not purposely or accidentally enter false/incorrect emails. Example, if some user wants to make an account he could enter a random email and the actual owner of the email won't be able to make an account!

You probably know how to set the object Id, but heres an example in Obj-C, and then you would need to save the User:

```
  PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
  user.username = currentUser.objectId;
```